# TypeScript passes method name instead of parameter value to .Net Core

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, .net-core

Why does the following code end up passing "getFullReport" as the eventId when it lands on the .Net Core 3.1 side, and not the actual eventId value?

I have verified with a `console.log` statement here prior to the call that `eventId` is the proper ID I am expecting to see on the .Net Core side, but when I set a breakpoint there, the `eventId` comes across as the name of the TypeScript method (`getFullReport`) and not the Id that is shown prior to the call on the client-side.

```
  getFullReport(eventId: string) {

    var params = new HttpParams();
    params.append('eventId', eventId);

    this.http.get<AccidentDetails>('api/accidents/getfullreport', { params: params }).subscribe(
      result => {
        this.accidentDetails = result;
      },
      error => console.error(error)
    );

  }
```

The .Net Core code is:

```
[HttpGet("{eventId}")]
public FullReport GetFullReport(string eventId)
```

This eventId is not the one I am trying to send from the client.

Comment: Can you post the context when the function is invoked?.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter inside of the `HttpGet` attribute is the route of the endpoint. When you put the name of a variable (like so: `{variable_name}`) in the route, that means that, you should map that token of the path to the variable with the corresponding name. So, you're seeing `eventId` being equal to `getFullReport`, because you've set up the path as follows:
`api/accidents/getFullReport`
meaning that you're hitting the path `api/accidents/{eventId}` where `eventId` = `getFullReport`. Does that make sense?

To remedy this, do:

```cs
[HttpGet("getFullReport/{eventId}")]
public FullReport GetFullReport(string eventId)
```

Comment: If I change it to this attribute signature, it does not even call the API method (break-point never hit).  I get a 404 in the browser console.  I have tried changing the casing to match on both sides, just in case (no pun intended) but no luck.

Comment: I changed the call to `this.http.get<AccidentDetails>('api/Accidents/GetFullReport/' + eventId)` instead of using params, that was the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the attribute on the .Net Core side as per Matt Kae's suggested answer to:

`[HttpGet("GetFullReport/{eventId}")]`

Then I removed the `params` code in TypeScript and just called it by appending the `eventId` directly into the URL call:

`this.http.get<AccidentDetails>('api/Accidents/GetFullReport/' + eventId).subscribe()`

This resolved the issue.